# Slope and Intercept using only sample size, mean, and standard deviation.

Tags: statistics

I have been tasked with finding the simple linear regression model slope and intercept of two sets of data, but the only have access to the sample size, mean, and standard deviations of each set of data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only information you have are univariate statistics. So you don't have a clue about the link between the two variables. In order to find the linear regression, you need to know the covariance or the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Not only is it impossible, there isn't even a way to make a vaguely acceptable guess. Consider the situation where you have some given, sorted $x$ data and the $y$ data is exactly the $x$ data. Then your line should be $y=x$. Now reverse the order of the $y$ data while leaving the $x$ the same. Then your line should be $y=x_N-x$, where $x_N$ was the last value of $x$. These lines have opposite slopes, but the mean and standard deviation of $y$ have not changed (since the data *set* has not changed, only its order has changed).